# TypeError: this.state.datacharts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

please help, I got a problem with my code, have seen some of the similar issues, but didn’t find why this happens. I got an error. TypeError: this.state.datacharts.map is not a function .. please help where the error is, because I was just reactjs
this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactSpeedometer from "react-d3-speedometer"

// Resolves charts dependancy
const API = 'http://localhost:9000/Sales_vs_Target';

class Chart_SalesVsTarget extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      datacharts: '' 
    };
}

callAPI() {
  fetch(API)
      .then(res => res.text())
      // .then(res => this.setState({res}, () => 
      //   console.log('Datacharts fetched...', res)))
      .then(res => this.setState({ datacharts: res }));
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.callAPI();
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center><h4>Sales vs Target</h4></center>
      <a href='/Table_nas'>
             <center>
               <div>
             {/* {this.props.apiResponse.map(apiResponses => */}
             <div style={{
                width: '500px',
                height: '300px',
                background: '#e4e5e6'
              }}>
              {this.state.datacharts.map(apiResponses => 
                <ReactSpeedometer
                  fluidWidth
                  minValue={0}
                  maxValue={100}
                  value={apiResponses.PERSEN_NAS}
                />
                )}
              </div>

               </div>
             </center>
         </a>
         </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chart_SalesVsTarget;
```

Comment: did you  console log `this.state.datacharts` to see if it's an array and has the values you want first?

Comment: hmm its unclear whether your response data is a string or an array. From the looks of it, you turned the data into a string by using res.text(). So even if you used it to update your state, you wouldnt be able to use .map() since that is an array method. To better assist you, we need to know whether "res" is an array, object, string or etc.

Answer (score 2):

Before ComponentDidMount is called, the render function will run with initial props and state.
You did set the initial state to `datacharts: ""`, which is a string. But String has no method `String.map()`, so it errors out.

I recommend using, inside the constructor, `this.state = { datacharts: [] }`